# Search Controller Scroll with tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar

search controller with tableview is working fine. I have to set the position and hide/show the search controller it's working at the table view header, when tableview scrolling after it's not showing at first time click search bar button at navigation bar. when I double click search button search bar controller is showing. I have to show the search controller with single click of search button after tableview scrolling

this is code of search controller

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) 
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

{
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil

 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.delegate = self

        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()


        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil


}



 func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {


        _ = kidsData

        let searchToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text

        if(searchToSearch == "")
        {
            self.kidsData = self.KidsDataDuplicate

        }
        else{

            self.kidsData.removeAll()

            let itemsarray = self.KidsDataDuplicate

            var forkidsinArray = \[String\]()

            for Kids in itemsarray {

                forkidsinArray.append(Kids.name)
                if(Kids.name.range(of: searchToSearch!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)
                {
                    self.kidsData.append(Kids)

                }

            }
          }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

hide and unhide code 


    var launchBool: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if launchBool == true {

                tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
                       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                      self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)


            } else {
                tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
                myInt = 0
            }
        }
    }


 @IBAction func NAVSearchButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        launchBool = !launchBool    
    }
```

[image]

after tableview scrolling when I click of search button at navigation search bar controller is not showing when I double click the search button its showing how to fix search controller with tableview when scrolling pls help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly then add seperate `UISearchbar` inside attribute inspector after the `navigation item` and then add below `UITableView`. Pinned the constraints. Now your search bar will be always visible. In your case search bar is the set to table header view. So that when you were scrolling search bar is also getting scrolled

Comment: how to fix the search controller when scrolling tableview. when I click search button show and hide option should be work